# Как происходит перезапуск Django/Flask при изменении в файлах?

Tags: python, django, flask, wsgi

1. Как происходит перезапуск django при изменении кода во время работы пользователей?
   Хочу понять как это технически происходит
2. Т.е. я так понимаю во время запуска все файлы подгружаются в оперативку?
   Перезапускаются ли все файлы сразу или например если я изменил один файл то только один файл и перезагрузится? Перезапуск это фактически загрузка с диска в оперативку?
3. Доставляет ли это проблемы производительности?
   И лучше ли делать перезапуск например раз в день, чем при каждом изменении?

Может быть посоветуете литературу где поподробней это описано.

Comment: Во-первых, перезапуск полный. Во-вторых, перезапуск работает только в окружении для разработки — а значит вам должно быть пофиг на производительность, вам же работать надо

Comment: @andreymal т.е. на продакшене перезапуск не работает? а как обновляется продакшен? не могу найти нормальной информации по организации именно продакт разработки, а не уроков начальных. Где можно про это почитать?

Comment: Вы точно знаете, когда и как обновляете продакшен, а значит прописать команду перезапуска в процесс обновления для вас не составит никаких проблем

Comment: Ок. Но тогда вопрос на сколько это проблемно для производительности ? Много ли это может занимать времени и что делать если система должна работать 24/7 ?

Comment: Ну вы же не редактируете файлы проекта 24/7 круглосуточно? Зачем тогда нужен автоматический перезапуск?

Comment: Нет. С автоматическим я понял. Вопрос уже про простой перезапуск

Comment: Тогда можно запускать две копии и перезапускать их по очереди; пока одна перезапускается — обслуживать пользователей будет другая. Ну и вообще хорошо выкатить проект на несколько разных серверов для отказоустойчивости, балансировка нагрузки, blue-green deployment, rolling update, вот это вот всё

Comment: Спасибо. Понял. А где можно почитать про правильное устройство продакшена? Может книгу какую нибудь порекомендуете ?